# Display Today-Tomorrow as per date from server

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, react-native

i want to Display Today or Tomorrow as per Date received from the server..

my date format is **Thu Jun 22 2018 10:00:00 GMT+0530**.

i want to display **Tomorrow** instead of **Thu Jun 22 2018 10:00:00 GMT+0530**.

Comment: are you using moment? https://momentjs.com/

Comment: yes i am using momentjs

Answer (score 1):

You can get the server date string returned, convert it to a Date object and then increment or decrement the date to get tomorrow or yesterday:

```
var dateServerReturned = 'Fri Jun 22 2018 10:00:00 GMT+0530'; // <-- in this example case

var dateServerToHandleTomorrow = new Date(dateServerReturned);
var dateServerToHandleYesterday = new Date(dateServerReturned);
var tomorrow = new Date(dateServerToHandleTomorrow.setDate(dateServerToHandleTomorrow.getDate()+1));
var yesterday = new Date(dateServerToHandleYesterday.setDate(dateServerToHandleYesterday.getDate()-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try to use

```
moment.fromNow(date)
```

Comment: fromNow only gives 'a few seconds ago'
not actual day diffrence

Answer (score 1):

well, so try to check if date is today or tomorrow to display. Bellow is my way, hope this help.

```
global.REFERENCE = moment(); 
global.TODAY = global.REFERENCE.clone().startOf('day');
global.YESTERDAY = global.REFERENCE.clone().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day');
global.A_WEEK_OLD = global.REFERENCE.clone().startOf('isoweek');

export function formatDate(time) {
    let momentDate = moment(time);
    if (isToday(momentDate)) {
        return momentDate.format('LT');
    } else if (isYesterday(momentDate)) {
        return getIntl().formatMessage(Messages.yesterday);
    } else if (isWithinAWeek(momentDate)) {
        return momentDate.format('dddd');
    }
    return momentDate.format('l');
}

export function isToday(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isSame(global.TODAY, 'd');
}

export function isYesterday(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isSame(global.YESTERDAY, 'd');
}

export function isWithinAWeek(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isAfter(global.A_WEEK_OLD);
}

export function isTwoWeeksOrMore(momentDate) {
    return !isWithinAWeek(momentDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you uses moment then follow....

```js
Math.abs(moment('pass your server date here').diff(moment(new Date()),‘days’))===0? ‘Today’: Math.abs(moment('pass your server date here').diff(moment(new Date()),‘days’))===1?'Tomorrow':'Anything else'
```

Comment: `moment()` already returns object with current date, there's no need using `moment(new Date())`. Consider also assigning diff's result to variable instead of calling it twice.

Comment: And using `Math.abs` will result in displaying "Tomorrow" also for yesterday's date